# How to get different length output using keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, time-series, lstm

I am working on a time-series kind of problem. I have `(timesteps, features)` and the length of output will be `(timesteps,)`. All outputs as float numbers. But the problem is I have training samples with different timesteps.
Suppose one example has 1500 timesteps then it will output 1500 dimensional vector. Another example has 1000 timesteps and it will have 1000 dimensional output.

I am looking for a way to train such a model using keras.

Answer (score 1):

**Its the number of features that has to remain consistent not the number of timestamps.**

Outputs will be batches of one row predictions, so in your case its 1500 and than 1000. Model does not care, features should remain same. And beware of dataleakage with time series.